# Removing ligatures for small caps in TeX4HT

Tags: small-caps, tex4ht, ligatures, htlatex

The Amazon Kindle has a default font which features small caps and ligatures, but not ligatures for small caps. For this reason, when it sees ligatures (even common ones, such as "ﬀ"), it renders them in lowcase instead, which is ugly.

I wouldn't like to disable ligatures for everything, but having lowcase letters in the middle of a small caps word is ugly.

Is there a way (preferably using `.4ht` files) to disable ligatures in small caps?

Is there maybe a way to disable small caps for a given environment/string?

Edit:

Apparently, this is a generic problem with CSS and `font-variant: small-caps` as I get the same result in my browser.

Edit 2:

CSS3 adds a `font-variant-ligatures` setting to enable different kind of ligatures using OTF fonts. When using small caps with this setting, ligatures are automatically disabled, just as with LaTeX. However, not a lot of browsers implement it, and calibre's `ebook-convert`, which I use, does not seem to support it either.

Edit 3:

My problem with TeX4HT comes from the fact that I have redefined `\textsc` for Tex4HT:

```
% Reconfigure small caps
\NewConfigure{textsc}{2}
\renewcommand\textsc[1]{%
\a:textsc#1\b:textsc
}
\Configure{textsc}{\Tg<span class="small-caps">}{\Tg</span>}
\Css{span.small-caps{
font-variant:small-caps;
}}
```

The reason for doing so is that TeX4HT's default converts all letters to uppercase and creates one `<span>` tag per character, which is heavy, ugly, and does not produce real small-caps (although it does prevent ligatures, since all letters are enclosed in `<span>` tags). So I'd rather use a cleaner approach, by disabling ligatures in TeX and using one `<span>` element only, without changing letters to uppercase.

Also, I run TeX4HT with `htlatex doc.tex 'ebook.cfg,xhtml,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'`

Comment: see http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-307647-tex4ht-unicode-used-when-not-needed-help-165917591.html

Comment: but I cannot get it to work

Comment: @michal.h21: this is to disable all ligatures anyway, but I only want to disable them in small caps.

Comment: How are the small caps made in you document?  A minimal document `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textsc{sufficient}
\end{document}` run through `htlatex` has no ligatures.

Comment: Oh! I just understood why `htlatex` produces one `<span>` node per letter… I found the produced document ugly (also, not really small caps), so I redefined `\textsc` in my `.4ht` in order to have a single `<span>` tag…

Comment: I updated the question with these informations.

Comment: Can you provide more details.  `ebook.cfg` doesn't appear to be a standard file.  Putting your code in to such a file, produces errors for me, unless I move it to after the `xhtml` option on the command line, and then I still get each character in a separate `span`

Comment: `ebook.cfg` is a configuration file for TeX4HT, added to the command line. In my case, it only contains CSS to tune the look of the produced HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might make use of the following code to suppress character level `<span>` node creation:

```
\Configure{htf}{4}{+}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}
```

so that you will get:

```
<span class="cmcsc-10">sufficient</span>
```

which is the default behavior when character level `<span>` node is suppressed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if [microtype](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/microtype) is compatible with `tex4ht`, but `microtype` can disable ligature, both for fonts and individually. See section 8 in the manual.

The code would be something like:

```
\usepackage[protrusion=false}{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[ff,ffi,fj,fi]{encoding = *, family = sc* }
```

*Disclaimer*: Untested!

Comment: It sounds like a good idea. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I've tried adding to to `<myclass>.4ht` and `<mysettings>.cfg` and it won't do anything…

Comment: Perhaps you can run the html-file `tex4ht` produce through a search and replace filter: `search "ligature" replace "the letters"`?

Comment: Did you try `microtype` with `protrusion=false` `tex4ht` produces .dvi-files, doesn’t it?. `microtype` is mainly for .pdf.

Comment: The search and replace is what I've been doing so far, using `sed` in a post-build script. I'd rather get rid of that if possible.

Comment: From the documentation of `microtype` it seems to be compatible with `tex4ht`. The source has `hooks` with reference to `tex4ht` (see the entry in the manuals index). I have to admit that I do not have the necessary skills to  sort out how to get the two packages to interact, if possible.