# Small caps inside hyperlinks make tex4ht render open-double-quote as backslash

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

Turning a book I just finished into an ebook, I ran into two (I thought unrelated) problems.  The more vexing one was that the open-double-quote was being turned into a backslash after a point very early on.  The second was that at some point the font went wonky and I was getting character-level `<span>`s for the bulk of the book, which I was able to work around using the excellent answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/removing-ligatures-for-small-caps-in-tex4ht/71495#71495) related to \Configure{htf}. Coming up with an MWE for this post, I discovered that they are related.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
``This renders correctly''

{\sc Do small caps break it?} ``No"

\hyperlink{a}{How about hyperlinks?} ``No"

\hyperlink{a}{\sc But... small caps inside hyperlinks} make everything afterwards render as
small caps, and break the ``double quotes,'' though not the `single quotes.'

\end{document}
```

This renders just fine in LaTeX... "But... small caps inside hyperlinks" is rendered in small caps, and the text afterwards is normal, with normal double quotes.  However, compiling it with `htlatex test.tex "xhtml"` gives HTML with character-level spans that persist after the hyperlink, and the opening double quote is rendered as backslash.

I discovered that I could work around this by putting a `\normalfont` at the end of the hyperlink text.  It still renders the small caps with character-level spans but I should post that as another question, I suppose.

So I will mark this as "answered," but I wanted to post it to point out what looks to be  a bug in tex4ht, and in case anyone has a similar problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\textsc` and not the deprecated command `\sc`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
``This renders correctly''

\textsc{Do small caps break it?} ``No''

\hyperlink{a}{How about hyperlinks?} ``No''

\hyperlink{a}{\textsc{But... small caps inside hyperlinks}} make everything afterwards render as
small caps, and break the ``double quotes,'' though not the `single quotes.'

\end{document}
```

This is the output after `htlatex test.tex "xhtml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="kuhn.tex" /> 
<meta name="date" content="2014-08-31 19:32:00" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kuhn.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 6--><p class="noindent" >&#8220;This renders correctly&#8221;
</p><!--l. 8--><p class="indent" >   <span 
class="cmcsc-10">D<span 
class="small-caps">o</span> <span 
class="small-caps">s</span><span 
class="small-caps">m</span><span 
class="small-caps">a</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span> <span 
class="small-caps">c</span><span 
class="small-caps">a</span><span 
class="small-caps">p</span><span 
class="small-caps">s</span> <span 
class="small-caps">b</span><span 
class="small-caps">r</span><span 
class="small-caps">e</span><span 
class="small-caps">a</span><span 
class="small-caps">k</span> <span 
class="small-caps">i</span><span 
class="small-caps">t</span>? </span>&#8220;No&#8221;
</p><!--l. 10--><p class="indent" >   <a 
href="#a">How about hyperlinks?</a> &#8220;No&#8221;
</p><!--l. 12--><p class="indent" >   <a 
href="#a"><span 
class="cmcsc-10">B<span 
class="small-caps">u</span><span 
class="small-caps">t</span>... <span 
class="small-caps">s</span><span 
class="small-caps">m</span><span 
class="small-caps">a</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span> <span 
class="small-caps">c</span><span 
class="small-caps">a</span><span 
class="small-caps">p</span><span 
class="small-caps">s</span> <span 
class="small-caps">i</span><span 
class="small-caps">n</span><span 
class="small-caps">s</span><span 
class="small-caps">i</span><span 
class="small-caps">d</span><span 
class="small-caps">e</span> <span 
class="small-caps">h</span><span 
class="small-caps">y</span><span 
class="small-caps">p</span><span 
class="small-caps">e</span><span 
class="small-caps">r</span><span 
class="small-caps">l</span><span 
class="small-caps">i</span><span 
class="small-caps">n</span><span 
class="small-caps">k</span><span 
class="small-caps">s</span></span></a> make everything afterwards
render as small caps, and break the &#8220;double quotes,&#8221; though not the &#8216;single
quotes.&#8217;
</p>

</body></html>
```

and you see that the small caps are properly segregated.

Comment: Thanks, I see that works too... Would love to know how to solve the per-character `<span>`s (I see that I didn't do the right markdown for `<span>` above, I'll edit that.

Comment: @NatKuhn That's much beyond my almost inexistent knowledge of `tex4ht`.

Answer (score 0):

As I point out in the text above, inserting a `\normalfont` at the end of the hyperlink text works around this bug.

I would welcome other answers.